# Why is typescript not able to determine the required return type from the class template parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I was trying to create a light, strongly typed Hook framework that uses objects of Hook-classes as events when I encountered this issue.

In the following code, the `t instanceof PostCreate` correctly identifies that `t.args` is an object that holds a "key" string (see first template parameter of `PostCreate`). However, it is not able to identify that number is a correct `ReturnType`.

```js
abstract class Hook<ArgsType, ReturnType=void> {
   constructor(public readonly args: ArgsType){}
}

class PostCreate extends Hook<{key: string}, number>{}

function on<ArgType, ReturnType, T extends Hook<ArgType, ReturnType>>(t: T): ReturnType|undefined {
    if (t instanceof PostCreate){
        console.log(t.args.key) // no type error
        return 5 // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType'.
    }
    return undefined;

}

console.log(
    on(new PostCreate({key: "my value"}))
)
```

While I am interested in understanding this, I am also curious for other solutions to the same problem.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=9#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgEge2wawB4BBKAczABUBPABwFMAaBAJTogFcoA7a+gXgBu2AJYATAHwIA3gCgE82Ni6Qo7eNigAKGuxDJhsBFDrBRS5FQTAyYAFwIS5XnQCUUgL4zPMlGgwAFbEgAYWNgCDoEOgAPCK5RDBx8Aik8Oip7FWEuUncmLnYAWxA6KHEPGRkAM3YueGElBCViMmcmVg5uNoQKKNi6eMTcQkdujs4eWjpxcU0IewoXe3GuqYAfWtE6Kuy6UWk5eQRhKoQ54+UIYDq6bFPAkLCIt0Ojo8VlbGQ6ADpkbFIcx+1nIPzSVBcCAA9FCEFxsAgIFMolAoBpXm8jGwJggAKzQ2HOBAAcgKxVKxOOGHhiD8wlIXFA30RCKR9BJK0m9GJPwxnjexk6XAQm22u1EAG5Kt4PmAvr9-oCMUpNFw6AB3BAPCChEwRTSpdL2ABEhUsAmAyHYdGN7hcLhkLiAA) for those interested

*Edit: More findings*

It seems like Typescript treats the ReturnType as unknown. When I try to explicitly cast using the `infer` keyword, it mentions that the ReturnType is unknown.

```js
abstract class Hook<ArgsType, ReturnType=void> {
   constructor(public readonly args: ArgsType){}
}

class PostCreate extends Hook<{key: string}, number>{}

type InferReturnType<T> = T extends Hook<any, infer R> ? R : any;

function on< T extends Hook<any, any>>(t: T): InferReturnType<T> | undefined {
    if (t instanceof PostCreate){
        console.log(t.args.key) // no type error
        return 5 as InferReturnType<PostCreate> // Error: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'InferReturnType<T>'.
    }
    return undefined;

}

console.log(
    on(new PostCreate({key: "my value"}))
)
```

*Edit2: Clarification*

This solution works, but is very "centralised". An aim would be to define events in a more decentralised way. Another disadvantage of this approach is that it would be difficult to implement a generic way of merging group implementations.

```
interface Hooks{
    post_create?: (input: {key: string})=> number;
    pre_create?: (input: {key: number})=> string;
}

class HookImplementation implements Hooks{
    post_create({key}: {key: string}): number{
        return key.length
    }
}

const hook_impl: Hooks = new HookImplementation();

console.log(hook_impl.pre_create?.({key: 34}))
```

Comment: In order to make it work, you should overload your method. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/mbAe8N). TS just don't support using generic as an argument type and return type.

Comment: This solution bypasses the error I was experience, but is basically doesn't do any type checking on the return value. I am specifically looking for a solution that allows strong typing of the return value. Overloading is an interesting track though, thanks!

Comment: You can add user defined typeguard

Answer (score 1):

Let's take something simpler, but relative to your question:

```js
function test<ReturnType>(): ReturnType | undefined {
    return 5;
}
```

If you try this code, it will fail with error:

> Type '5' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType | undefined'

And this is OK, because ReturnType can be anything:

```js
const fake = test<string>();
```

TS treat fake as string, but in reality it's a number, whoops!

The way to handle is - get rid of ReturnType and in your case this might looks like this:

```js
abstract class Hook<ArgsType, ReturnType=void> {
   constructor(public readonly args: ArgsType){}
}

class PostCreate extends Hook<{key: string}, number>{}

console.log(
    on(new PostCreate({key: "my value"}))
)


function on<ArgType, T extends Hook<ArgType>>(t: T) {
    if (t instanceof PostCreate){
        console.log(t.args.key) // no type error
        return 5 // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType'.
    }
    return undefined;

}

console.log(
    on(new PostCreate({key: "my value"}))
)
```

No error for now.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that now we can easily have an implementation of `on` that is wrong. For example, it might return a string, object or anything basically, without the typescript compiler every complaining

Comment: Might be function overloading might help?